# subdomain rails nginx unicorn how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I am trying to have a new rails app in sub domain, i tried few and i'm unable to solve it.

i have sub domain xxx.domain.com 
and i'm tryin to have new sub domain yyy.domain.com

This is my nginx config file

```
upstream unicorn1 {
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.xxx.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
upstream unicorn2 {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.yyy.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xxx.domain.com;
  root /home/ubuntu/apps/xxx/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn1;
  location @unicorn1 {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn1;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name yyy.domain.com;
  root /home/ubuntu/apps/yyy/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn2;
  location @unicorn2 {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn2;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

}
```

The other subdomain i.e, yyy.domain.com always show the site xxx.domain.com

How do i point yyy.domain.com to check my app?

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: can you show your unicorn config files ? (and especially : their `#listen` instruction)

Comment: Also, you mention in tags it's about capistrano. Showing capistrano tasks that restart apps may help.